# CodeIgniter Pagination wrong generate next link

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm Quit New and trying to Make Pagination Inside Codeigniter...
I'm to create pagination with one extra argument.. link first argument is for getting ID for database search.. and than create pagination... I've done so far but the next page link is not correct as it should be. please check my code and let me know what's wrong i am doing.

this is model code..
my modelclass name is `movie`

```
public function get_movies_by_actor($actor_id,$num=10,$start=0)
{
    $this->db->select(" f.film_id,
                        f.language_id,
                        a.actor_id,
                        f.title,
                        f.description,
                        l.name AS language,
                        c.name AS category,
                        concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name ) AS actor_name
                    ",FALSE);
    $this->db->from('actor AS a');
    $this->db->join('film_actor AS fa', 'fa.actor_id=a.actor_id');
    $this->db->join('film AS f', 'f.film_id=fa.film_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('language AS l', 'l.language_id=f.language_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('film_category AS fc', 'f.film_id=fc.film_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('category AS c', 'c.category_id=fc.category_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('a.actor_id', $actor_id);
    $this->db->order_by('f.film_id','desc')->limit($start,$num);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

this and controller code.
my controller class name is `movies`

```
public function actor_movie($actor_id,$start=0)
{
    $data['movies']=$this->movie->get_movies_by_actor($actor_id,$start,10);
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/movies/actor_movie/'.$actor_id.'/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->movie->get_total_movies();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Older Post &rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt Newer Post';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['pagination_links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['title'] = '$this->pagination->create_links()';

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('actor_movies',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: you need to add $config['uri_segment'] for your pagination segment, in your case it will be 4 here is the setting $config['uri_segment'] = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just you need to add `uri_segment` in pagination $config array in Controller Function...

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```